# Number of days between two dates not based on time

Tags: android, jodatime

I save a date and then compare that against the current date using

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
introDateTimeSaved = formatter.parseDateTime(introDateViewedString);
introDays = Days.daysBetween(introTodaysDate, introDateTimeSaved);
```

in order to determine how many days it has been since the saved date has been updated. This is to show how long ago a particular button has been pressed. The problem is that the days goes off of 24 hours and I want it to go off purely days. For instance:

Saved Date Variable: 2016-10-15 08:26:00

Today Date Variable 2016-10-16 08:25:00

This returns a difference in days of 0 and my best guess is because the time between these two dates is 23 hours and 59 minutes. I want this to return 1 since its a difference of 1 day from the 15th to the 16th or return 2 if its the 14th and today is the 16th ect etc.

Comment: Why accepting such a complex answer? Just convert your `DateTime`-objects (which should rather have been `LocalDateTime` because of missing time zone in input) to `LocalDate`-objects and then determine the difference in days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying an hour-based solution as suggested before is dangerous and often wrong. Proof choosing an input around a daylight-saving-change (in my local timezone Europe/Berlin):

```
String introDateViewedString = "2016-03-26 00:00:00";
String introTodaysDateString = "2016-03-31 00:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime introDateTimeSaved = formatter.parseDateTime(introDateViewedString);
DateTime introTodaysDate = formatter.parseDateTime(introTodaysDateString);

System.out.println(introDateTimeSaved); // 2016-03-26T00:00:00.000+01:00
System.out.println(introTodaysDate); // 2016-03-31T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

Following code proves that an hour-based solution is generally wrong:

```
Hours hours = Hours.hoursBetween(introDateTimeSaved, introTodaysDate);
System.out.println(hours); // PT119H
System.out.println(hours.getHours() / 24); // 4 (should be 5)
```

And following code proves that just using `period.getHours()` is a bad idea because that method only yields a partial amount and ignores the fact that the period in question can also contain other units:

```
Period p = new Period(introDateTimeSaved, introTodaysDate); // P5D
System.out.println(p); // P5D
int days = p.getHours() / 24;
System.out.println(days); // 0 (period does not contain hours but days)
```

So what is the best approach?

**Use plain calendar dates if you are not interested in clock time!**

```
String introDateViewedString = "2016-03-26 00:00:00";
String introTodaysDateString = "2016-03-31 00:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime introDateTimeSaved = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(introDateViewedString);
LocalDateTime introTodaysDate = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(introTodaysDateString);

LocalDate date1 = introDateTimeSaved.toLocalDate(); // 2016-03-26
LocalDate date2 = introTodaysDate.toLocalDate(); // 2016-03-31

System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays()); // 5
```

This solution has also the advantage not to use any home-grown calculation based on dividing numbers etc. Using such arithmetic in context of date and time should let users ring the alarm bells (in most cases).

Comment: Thanks this is the kind of info I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the difference in hours intead, then divide by `24` and round down.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
introDateTimeSaved = formatter.parseDateTime(introDateViewedString);

Period p = new Period(introDateTimeSaved, introTodaysDate);
int hours = p.getHours();
int days =  Math.floor(hours/24.0);
```

EDIT:

Interval was calculated using [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) as the JDK `Date` API is horrible to manipulate.

Comment: Saved Date 15 Oct 07:00:00 Todays Date 15 Oct 20:00:00 leaves 13 hours. 13/24 = 5.4166 rounded up = 1. That should equal 0.

Comment: And I am using joda time

Comment: What if it was between `Saved Date 15 Oct 07:00:00` and  `Todays Date 16 Oct 20:00:00`, would you consider it `1` or `1` days? it would be `37/24` hours = `1.54`... If you say `0`, all you have to do is use the rounding as `floor` instead of `ceil`, right?

Comment: 15 to 15 oct should be 0. 15 to 16 oct should be 1 regardless of time. 15 oct 23:00:00 to 16 oct 01:00:00 should be 1.

Comment: @th3ramr0d So round down it is. I edited my answer to have `floor` instead of `ceil` :)

Comment: I think your answer is unfortunately flawed, see examples in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int dayDifference= ((int)((startDate.getTime()/(24*60*60*1000)) - (int)(endDate.getTime()/(24*60*60*1000))));
```

This is using standard java.util.Date class, by the way.